# Expand or position Gantt chart to take two columns of space

Tags: positioning, pgfgantt, gantt

How do I expand or position the Gantt chart so that it would take up two columns of my two-column layout, without adjusting the amount of text that comes before it or reordering sections, of course?

Here's the source code of the chart:

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{ganttchart}[
        hgrid,
        vgrid,
        x unit=1.8mm,
        inline,
        time slot format=isodate,
        expand chart=2\textwidth
    ]{2024-01-23}{2024-04-26}
    \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name, week=1} \\
    \ganttbar{Porting to Android}{2024-01-23}{2024-02-15} \\
    \ganttbar{Rewrite of benchmarks}{2024-01-23}{2024-02-29} \\
    \ganttbar{Exploration of tunable parameters for energy efficiency}{2024-02-22}{2024-03-28} \\
    \ganttbar{Further background work}{2024-02-22}{2024-03-28} \\
    \ganttbar{Work on poster}{2024-03-28}{2024-04-10} \\
    \ganttbar{Final report polishing}{2024-03-28}{2024-04-26} \\
      %\ganttmilestone{Milestone}{7} \ganttnewline
\end{ganttchart}
}
```

Two-column text layout, with Gantt chart positioned at the beginning of the second column and flowing outside of the page, while the lower part of the first column is empty. Preferrably, I want it to be located at the bottom of the page, taking up both columns, while text would continue to flow outside of it.

[image: Two-column text layout, with Gantt chart positioned at the beginning of the second column and flowing outside of the page, while the lower part of the first column is empty]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Without the rest of the document it is hard to say, but maybe putting `\begin{figure*}` before the chart and `\end{figure*}` after it would work (i.e., create a floating full-width figure without a caption).

Comment: @Marijn indeed it does work, thank you! Apologies for not including a full compilable snippet, but this solves it